# Square of the distance function on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold. Consider the square of the distance function
$$dist^2\colon M\times M\to \mathbb{R}$$
given by $(x,y)\mapsto dist^2(x,y)$. It is easy to see that this function is infinitely smooth near the diagonal.

Now fix a point $a\in M$. **Consider the Taylor series of $dist^2$ at $(a,a)$ in some coordinate system (say normal). Can one compute explicitly its coefficients up to the third order?**

Comment: All the coefficients of degree 3 vanish.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fix a point $x_0 \in M$. Then let $x = \exp_{x_0}(t v)$ and $y=\exp_{x_0}(t w)$, with $v,w \in T_{x_0}M$.

Then we have the following formula for the distance squared between two geodesic emanating from $x_0$

$$ d^2(\exp_{x_0}(t v),\exp_{x_0}(t w)) = |v-w|^2t^2-\frac{1}{3}R(v,w,w,v) t^4 + O(t^5)$$

whre $R$ is the Riemann curvature tensor. From here you can derive an expression where you follow the two geodesics for different times (just rescale $w \to s/t w$), that is

$$ d^2(\exp_{x_0}(t v),\exp_{x_0}(s w)) = |v|^2t^2 +|w|s^2 -2 g(v,w) ts -\frac{1}{3}R(v,w,w,v) s^2 t^2 + O(|t^2+s^2|^{5/2})$$

Take now $|v| = |w|=1$, then $(t,v)$ and $(s,w)$ (both $\in [0,\epsilon) \times \mathbb{S}_{x_0}^{n-1}$) are polar coordinates of $x,y$. More explicitly, setting $t = d(x_0,x)$ and $s = d(x_0,y)$, you have

$$ d^2(x,y) = t^2 + s^2 - 2\cos\theta t s - \tfrac{1}{3} K_\sigma (1-\cos\theta^2)t^2 s^2 +  O(|t^2+s^2|^{5/2})$$

where $\cos\theta = g(v,w)$ is the angle between the two vectors and $K_\sigma$ is the sectional curvature of the plane $\sigma = \mathrm{span}(v,w)$.

As you can see, this can be used effectively as a purely metric definition of sectional curvature, with no connection or covariant derivative whatsoever.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Is there a standard reference?

Comment: I saw this formula in the book "Old and new" by Villani (Eq. 14.1 http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf). There is no proof there and the proof I've been able to write requires a not-so-short computation in normal coordinates (more precisely, one finds explicitly the tangent vector of the geodesic passing through $x$ and $y$ in normal coordinates around $x_0$). I would be happy to know of any other reference where that formula appears (maybe with a more conceptual proof that the one I described).

Comment: By the way, if you are interested in the proof I have it typed down already, but maybe it's a bit too long for an answer. Just tell me if you're interested.

Comment: Certainly I would be interested to see a proof.

Comment: I need an e-mail or something, so I can send it to you.

Comment: semyon@post.tau.ac.il

Comment: @Raziel  What  can  be  said  about  the  trajectories  of  the  gradient  vector  field  corresponds  to   function $f(x)=d^{2}(x_{0},x$? For  what  type  of  Riemanian  manifold  they  are  geodesics?

Comment: It's better to consider the function $\delta(x):= d(x_0,x)$. This satisfies the Eikonal equation $|\nabla\delta| = 1$ (at points where it is smooth). As a consequence its gradient flow trajectories are unit-speed geodesics emanating from $x_0$. If you consider the squared distance you still have geodesics, but not parametrized by constant speed. The picture is basically as in $\mathbb{R}^n$, what changes in general Riemannian manifolds is the occurrence of cut points $x \neq x_0$ where the distance fails to be smooth (or even differentiable).

Comment: Hi! @Raziel I would also be interested in seeing this proof.

Comment: @Raziel Thank you for your answer, that I jist saw. Just to double check, the formila is still true if we take $w$ to be $0,$ right? Then we'll have: $d^2(exp_p{tv},p)=t^2||v||^2+O(t^5),$ correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, in this case $d^2(exp_p tv,p) = t^2\|v\|^2$ (no remainder), until you hit the cut locus.

Answer (score 12):

The function $dist^2$ satisfies   a Hamilton-Jacobi equation. Using this  you can  find its Taylor expansion  at $(a,a)$ up to any order. In Appendix A of [this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/RandCrVal_p2.pdf) I  use this approach  to find  the degree 4 Taylor expansion  of this function; see Eq. (A.17) in the paper. The procedure  used in this appendix can be used to find the degree $6$ expansion as well, though the formulas become increasingly more complicated.  I should mention that this approach is also used in

B. DeWitt: The Global Approach to Quantum Field Theory, Oxford University Press, 2003,

pages 281-282, though the physicists' notation may be a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference. That's how one can prove that the remainder in my first formula is indeed O(t^6) and not O(t^5)! Btw, in the second formula after (A.10), $[B_\ell]_1$ should be $[A_\ell]_1$, right?

Comment: @Raziel Yes, you're right.