# References for local distance approximation over Riemannian manifolds

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Over a complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$, in a neighborhood of $p \in M$, the local distance can be approximated as follows: $\forall v,u \text{ unit vectors in } T_pM, \text{ and small } s, t$

$$ d ( Exp_p (tv) , Exp_p (su) ) = \sqrt{t^2 + s^2 - 2 st \cos \theta} \left( 1 - \kappa_p (v,u) \cdot O ( t s ) + O (t^2 s^2) \right) , $$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $u$ (in $T_pM$), and $\kappa_p (v,u)$ is the sectional curvature at $p$, along $v$ and $u$.

Is there a convenient textbook reference (with proof) for this?

**Edit**: Some nice discussions on this have happened here: [Square of the distance function on a Riemannian manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215573/square-of-the-distance-function-on-a-riemannian-manifold).

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, and voting to reopen: this post asks for a reference for the proof, which the linked post does not offer.

Comment: Thank you @AlexM. Glad to know that this question can make its contribution. How should I reopen this question?

Comment: It has already been placed into the "Reopen" queue. Now the community will vote for or against its reopening, there is not anything else that you can do but wait.

Comment: Got it. Thank you @AlexM.